# How to integrate arrows as a marker in google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jsp, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I implemented google map in jsp. everything is fine. our project is ITS(Intelligent Transport System). Here every time we have to track the vehicle and show its position and direction of vehicle in map.For that we used map and create markers according to `lat` and `lng` values we are getting. We use a `Bus` icon to show a vehicle but its not looking good. So we thought to change it to arrow (like Navigation in smartphone).

The code for creating marker is,

```
function createMarker(point, number,vn,position) {
var busimage="";
if(position=="same")
 {
     busimage="Resources/travel_bus1.png";
 }else if(position=="notsame")
     {
     busimage="Resources/travel_bus3.png";
     }

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: point,
              map: map,
              raiseOnDrag: true,
              icon:busimage,
             // animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
              draggable: false,
              zIndex: number,
              id:vn
          });

var html = number;

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Latitude: ' + point.lat() +
    '<br>Longitude: ' + point.lng()  + '<br>BusNo : '+ marker.get("id"), 
    maxwidth: 1000
});
```

So now we have to change bus icon to `arrow` icon and also we have to show the direction of the vehicle is moving. I have searched some online resources but it was useless. I am getting only implementing map in jsp. So can anyone help me to add arrow in map according to lat lng I am getting along with the direction. If you know any online resource also help full to me. Thank you . .

Comment: based on which information you would calculate the direction?

Comment: @Dr.Molle I think we can know the direction from latitude and longitude. .

Comment: How would you calculate a direction based on a single point?